# Memory leak in [UITableView _setupTableViewCommon] under ARC

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode4, instruments, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using the iOS Master/Detail template provided with XCode 4.2 (beta 4) with ARC for memory management, compiling for an iOS 4.3 target.

Instruments reports that all is fine with my code, but I have 2 x 32 byte leaks from a UIKit internal task "_setupTableViewController" within UITableView.

Is this something I need to worry about before submitting my app for evaluation?
If so, any hints on how to track and fix welcomed as the call tree says the problem is in class_createInstance of a dynlib!

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore it, especially if you are not getting any `Memory Warning: Level 1/2/3` in your console.